# Create new column with matched value between a unique set of item and a long list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am new to data wrangling in python. 
I have a column in a dataframe that has text like:

- I really like Product A!
- I think Product B is for me!
- I will go with Product C.

My objective is to create a new column with Product Name (Including the word 'Product'). I do not want to use Regex. Product name is unique in a row. So there will be no row with string such as

- I really like Product A and Product B

> **Problem in generic form**: I have a list of unique items. lets call it list A. I have another list of strings where each string includes atmost one of the items from list A. How do I create a new list with matched item.

I have written the following code. It works fine. But even I (new to progamming) can tell this is highly inefficient.

Any better and elegant solution?

```
product_type = ['Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C', 'Product D']
product_list = [None] * len(fed_df['product_line'])
for i in range(len(product_list)):
    for product in product_type:
        if product in fed_df['product_line'][i]:
            product_list[i] = product
fed_df['product_line'] = product_list
```

Comment: Could you post a small example of your data and the result you would expect? This would be much clearer and less prone to misinterpretation than your description above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short Background

Fundamentally, at some point, each element of each list will need to be compared similarly to how you've written it (although you can skip to the next loop once a match has been found). But the trick with writing good python code, is to utilise functionality written on a lower level for efficiency, rather than trying to write it yourself. For example: You should try to avoid using

```
for i in range(len(myList)): #code which accesses myList[i]
```

when you can use

```
for myListElement in myList: #code which uses myListElement
```

since in the latter, the accessing of myList is handled internally, and more efficiently than python calculating i manually, then accessing the i<sup>th</sup> element of myList. This fact is true of some other high-level programming languages too.

## Actual Answer

Anyway, to answer your question, I came up with the following and I believe it would be more efficient:

```
answer = map(lambda product_line_element: next(filter(lambda product: product in product_line_element,product_type),None), fed_df['product_line'])
```

What this does is it maps each line (map) of the fed_df['product_line'] and replaces that element with the first element (next) in a list containing the product types found in each line of products in fed_df['product_line'] (filter).

## How I tested

To test this I made a list of lists to use as fed_df['productline']

```
[['h', 'a', 'g'], ['k', 'b', 'l'], ['u', 't', 'a'], ['r', 'e', 'p'], ['g', 'e', 'b']]
```

and searched for "a" and "b" "product_types", which gave

```
['a', 'b', 'a', None, 'b']
```

as a result, which I think is what you are after...

These mapping functions are usually preferred over for loops, since it promotes no mutation, and can be made multi-threaded/multi-process more easily.

Another bonus of this solutions is that the result isn't calculated until future code attempts to access answer, which spreads the CPU usage a bit better. You can force it to be calculated by converting answer into a list (list(answer)), but it shouldn't be necessary.

I hope I understood your problem correctly. Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works too. I will get back to you after going through your code in detail.